# Eccentricity of vertices in a regular graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I was just trying to find out the eccentricity of the vertices in regular graphs, given in the link http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/reggraphs.html#CRG. Surprisingly, eccentricity is the same in all graphs except http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/REGGRAPHS/GIF/08_3_3-2.gif. I checked up to order 8. How can we show that the eccentricity of all vertices of regular graphs are the same or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $K_4$ and subdivide one edge (put a vertex of degree two in the middle of it). Now take two copies of the subdivided graph and add an edge joining the two
vertices of valency two. This new graph is cubic on 10 vertices and the eccentricities range from 3 to 5. This construction is easy to generalize; we can start with any pair of cubic graphs.

Answer (score 2):

There are further counterexamples: the [Folkman graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folkman_graph) is a $4$-regular graph on $20$ vertices with radius $3$ and diameter $4$.

The Folkman graph is semi-symmetric, which means that it is regular and edge-transitive but not vertex-transitive.  According to [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SemisymmetricGraph.html), no graph on fewer than $20$ vertices is semi-symmetric.  I don't know whether there are smaller examples of graphs that are regular but neither edge-transitive nor vertex-transitive.

Comment: The smallest asymmetric regular graphs are on 10 vertices, there are four of them and in two of them the eccentricities differ (if my calculations in sage are to be trusted).

Comment: any restriction on number of vertices and regularity so that the graph contains vertices of same eccentricity ?

Comment: @monalisa Sorry, I think that I initially misunderstood your original question.  I think that Chris Godsil's answer can be generalized to any regularity and to virtually any number of vertices: take $r - 1$ copies of any $r$-regular graph, subdivide an edge in each copy, and join together all of the edges of degree $2$ to get a new $r$-regular graph in which the eccentricities are not all the same.

Comment: then we may say that in some cases regular graphs have vertices of same eccentricity and in some cases its not.